# Compiler error when trying to run the below program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile and run the below code from command prompt. But when compiling I am getting error.

I am new to programming and I am new to java. How to resolve this error?

I am unable to find what is going wrong.

Below is the complete code:

```
package myprograms;

class Employee {

private String empID;
private String empName;
private int empPhoneNumber;

public String getEmpID() {
    return empID;
}
public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}
public int getEmpPhoneNumber() {
    return empPhoneNumber;
}
public void setEmpID(String empID) {
    this.empID = empID;
}
public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}
public void setEmpPhoneNumber(String empPhoneNumber) {
    try {
        this.empPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(empPhoneNumber);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid Phone number");
    }
}
public String toString() {
    return empID + " : " + empName + " : " + empPhoneNumber;
}

}
public class EmployeeData {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.setEmpID("e123");
    e1.setEmpName("Tom");
    try {
        e1.setEmpPhoneNumber("ertr");
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println(nfe.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.out.println(e1.toString());
        return;
    }

    if (e1.getEmpID().equals("e123")) {
        System.out.println("Welcome " + e1.getEmpName());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't let us guess what the error is. Always post it with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `return` statement in the `finally` block is the reason for compliation failure. Because the code below `try...catch...finally` is not reachable.

In general, there is no need of `return` statement in `finally` block.

A suggestion: It is good to write programs in `Notepad/Textpad` and compile/execute it from `Command-Line`. But, learn to use `Eclipse IDE` or any other `IDEs`. It would be very easy to handle these type of errors.

A 13 year old using Getters/Setters..!! Well done .. :)